# React: component only rendering new values on second onClick of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rendering

I making a react app and I have a parent component `Search` with child components `Input` and `Result`. `Input` has a drop down menu which passes a value, `genreValue`, to `Search`, through a callback function when a button is clicked. Search then makes an api call, which works fine.

My problem is it takes two clicks of the button for the new API data to render. Looking at other SO questions I suspect I need to pass `genreValue` as an argument to the cb function, or my onClick is only initialising, rather than invoking it on the first click.

It's a pretty simple app so I wouldn't think Flux etc would be needed. My console logs seem to show the value being changed in the `Search` and `Input` components. 
So what am I doing wrong?

**Search.js**

```
let Search = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      movies: ['Men In Black'],
      genreValue: '12'
    };
  },

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies()
  },

  getMovies(){
    let genre = this.state.genreValue;
    let url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?${key}&with_genres=${genre}`;
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log('response.body.results', response.body.results)
      this.setState({
        movies: response.body.results.map(function(movie){
          return movie.title
        })
      });
    });
  },

  handleGenre(newGenre) {
    this.setState({ genreValue: newGenre })
    return this.getMovies();
  },

  render(){
      console.log(this.state.movies)
      console.log('genreValue state', this.state.genreValue)
      return (
        <div>
          <Input genre={this.state.genreValue} onGenreChanged={this.handleGenre}/>
          <ul>
            {this.state.movies.map( function(movie){
              return <Results key={movie.id} data={movie}/>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
  }

});

export default Search;
```

**Input.js**

```
let Input = React.createClass ({

  selectHandler(){
    return this.props.onGenreChanged(this.refs.genre.value);
  },

  render() {
    console.log('genreValue prop', this.props.genre);
    console.log('refs', this.refs.genre)
      return <div>
      <select ref="genre">
        <option value="28">Action</option>
        <option value="12">Adventure</option>
        <option value="16">Animation</option>
        <option value="35">Comedy</option>
        <option value="80">Crime</option>
        <option value="99">Documentary</option>
        <option value="18">Drama</option>
        <option value="10751">Family</option>
        <option value="14">Fantasy</option>
        <option value="10769">Non-english</option>
        <option value="36">History</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick={this.selectHandler} value="Go">Go</button>
      </div>
    }
});

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `handleGenre` function, state may not have updated when `this.getMovies` is called. You could change it to the following:

`handleGenre(newGenre) {
    this.setState({ genreValue: newGenre }, function() {
        return this.getMovies();
    });
 },`

Or, probably better practice would be to call `this.getMovies` in a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function if `genreValue` has changed:

`componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.genreValue !== this.state.genreValue) {
        this.getMovies();
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks. I removed this.getMovies from handleGenre, so it only sets the genreValue in state, then added the componentDidUpdate with this.getMovies inside. I would not have thought state would take that long to change but there you go.

Comment: Yeah, I think this surprises a lot of people, but React does some fancy stuff for performance optimization and attempts to batch events. FYI, this is mentioned in the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html (Under "notes:")

And this blog post contains some more detailed info on when this occurs:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm